# Word order in a series of consecutive questions

Tags: word-order

I was wondering what happens to the word order when you have a list of consecutive questions like the one below:

"Are you following me? Or perhaps should I say that you're stalking me? Or maybe I'm reading this wrong?"

Should the last question be "or maybe am I reading this wrong?" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The last question should prolly be *or am I maybe reading this wrong?* but particularly with a second question like that, it's largely a matter of opinion.

Either way, doesn't that whole sequence seem rather contrived?